# Turning this Query into a Cursor

Tags: sql-server, cursor

This is what I have now, but I am still receiving errors:

> Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Line 239
>   A cursor with the name 'sumCurSalaryActiveEmps' does not exist.
>   Msg 16917, Level 16, State 2, Line 258
>   Cursor is not open.
>   Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Line 266
>   A cursor with the name 'sumCurSalaryActiveEmps' does not exist.
>   Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Line 267
>   A cursor with the name 'sumCurSalaryActiveEmps' does not exist.

```
DECLARE @sumCurSal decimal(10,2) 
DECLARE sumCurSalaryActiveEmp CURSOR Local FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT 
SUM(Salary.Emp_Salary) AS 'Sum of All Current Salaries'

    FROM
    (
    SELECT

        MAX(Emp_Salary_Change_Year) AS "Change Year"
        FROM Employee_Details AS e

    INNER JOIN Country AS co ON e.Emp_Country_Id = co.Country_Id
    INNER JOIN State AS s ON e.Emp_State_Id = s.State_Id
    INNER JOIN Designation AS d ON e.Desig_Id = d.Desig_Id
    INNER JOIN Salary AS sa ON e.Emp_Id = sa.Emp_Id
    WHERE Emp_Active = 1
    GROUP BY Emp_First_Name, Emp_Last_Name,
    Emp_Middle_Name, Country_Name, Desig_Name) AS C
    INNER JOIN Salary ON C.[Change Year] = Salary.Emp_Salary_Change_Year
    OPEN sumCurSalaryActiveEmps
    Fetch NEXT FROM sumCurSalaryActiveEmp
    INTO @sumCurSal

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        Fetch NEXT FROM sumCurSalaryActiveEmps 
            INTO @sumCurSal
            END
    close sumCurSalaryActiveEmps
    Deallocate sumCurSalaryActiveEmps
```

Comment: You should **avoid** cursors at all costs - not learn to create and use them!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It looks like you'll only get 1 row. Sum of all salaries. Why do you need a cursor?

Comment: Sql Server is not oracle.  Do NOT use cursors for 99.99999% of the time.  Which you should read as "I should never use a cursor".  Forget you even found this article : http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/sqlserver/sql-server-basics-of-cursors

Comment: I've read that I should avoid cursors but I would still like to know how to fix my code to make it into a working cursor. I'm trying to learn and see where my mistake is

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, your first mistake is that you are using a cursor.  This looks like a great place to use a CTE in my opinion and we can provide samples if needed.

Comment: You really need to give an example of what you are trying to achieve, you can think of a cursor as a way to take a row from a select statement and execute a statement on each.  The cursor you are employing only has a single value and based on the grouping logic would only have one row.  That would imply that it doesn't need a cursor at all.  Are you trying to get the Salary for each year?

Comment: I see you updated your query with the code that I provided in my answer.  Does your query execute correctly on its own?

Comment: yes, but when using a cursor, i get the above errors

Comment: It looks like you asked this same question as a CTE then tried it with a cursor. Which is your use case?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471935/cte-for-a-complex-query

Comment: I improved the formatting of the errors by  including them in a quote section.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all the folks who said you should not use cursors in general.  Its less that 1% when you really, really need one.  But, to answer your question, this is a template you can user for a cursor.

```
Declare sumCurSalaryActiveEmp Cursor Local Fast_Forward For
  -- Your select statement here.  For each column selected you need a corresponding variable to FETCH into

Open sumCurSalaryActiveEmp
Fetch Next From sumCurSalaryActiveEmp
  Into @sumCurSal -- YOU DECLARE These to match up to your select

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  Begin
     -- Do your stuff here
    Fetch Next From sumCurSalaryActiveEmp 
      Into @sumCurSal
  End

Close sumCurSalaryActiveEmp
Deallocate sumCurSalaryActiveEmp
```

In your specific code, you need to remove the keyword GO before your OPEN statement.